# Would it be possible to replace Dell Inspiron 15 7548 30-pin EDP display cable with a generic cable of the same type?

Tags: display, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair

My laptop's screen (Dell Inspiron 15 7548) requires a replacement cable, a 30-pin EDP. However the exact model of cable that was used would take a significant amount of time to ship from overseas, and I need my laptop back in use quickly.

Would it be possible to use a generic cable of the same type, or is the exact model used in the laptop by the manufacturer necessary?

Answer (score 0):

There are EDP cables to be found on Amazon that are
advertised as compatible with the Dell Inspiron 15 7548,
so this seems to be feasible.

The query
[EDP Display Cable Dell Inspiron 15 7548](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=EDP+Display+Cable+Dell+Inspiron+15+7548&i=electronics&ref=nb_sb_noss)
gives three possibilities, but these are just those that are specifically
said to be compatible with your exact model. Quite probably many others
are also compatible.

I don't know if just any cable will do, but ensure that wherever you buy it
has a good return policy.